# subtotal with product condition after applying date filter on google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I am struggling to find the right formula for my table. I have a database that I want to filter per date and get the total of each product on a different page.

As I need to prepare these products per day I would like to avoid counting every product by hand.
I have this formula =SUMIF(E40:E52,"Reese - box of 4*",D40:D52)that work without filter.

How can I do this function with filter?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCEpz.png)

My second question is about when an order as more than one product.Like here, we have a box of 4 that contains the product behind.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2B0D.png)
How can I get a count of the total number of each product, applying the filter option as well?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: To help us test your data, could you provide a sample spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11BoMwQg3kjdkRaJ99SfGWoAne9rgKVTDlEJTLxUFFaI/edit?usp=sharing